# Adding variety to reminder emails

Tags: email, user-engagement

Between once and 3 times a week (depending on user's settings), something new to do on our product comes up (always on the same days at 9 am, on monday, wednesday and friday).

Until now, we have sent simple email reminders each time. We feel that we could make those reminder emails more user-friendly, basically make the user come back on our product without sounding too much like a reminder, for example:

- Introduce features that the user could be interested in
- Give some tips
- even some random facts, why not.
- etc...

The goal is to make the user come use our product.

Because those reminders alone already send between 1 and 3 emails a week, we force ourselves not to send any other emails (except the necessary ones). This would be a good way not to increase email count and still provide a better experience.

Note that we haven't received any complaint about the number of emails sent, and the power users (really motivated ones) almost all advocated for more reminders.

Advantages:

- User should open the email more often
- Provides useful information according to where the user is in his journey
- Softer reminder (better UX)
- Doesn't increase the amount of email sent

Disadvantages:

- Mix content?
- User could disable this channel and lose this extra useful information

Questions:

1. Is it a good idea to mix a reminder with other information?
2. If we do, should it still be written as a reminder with the data being extra, or just forget the reminder part, thinking about the product will be enough as a reminder so no need to mention it?

Comment: Does user have option to switch reminders off completely? What are percentages of users who receive 0, 1, 2 and 3 reminders per week?

Comment: They can switch between 1 and 3 anytime.
In term of percentage, 40% for 1, 40% for 2 and 20% for 3. For now, it's not possible to choose 0, but it will be later on with more channels like slack etc...

Comment: Nope it should be your Choice how you want your information to have a reminder or not an yes you should be able to turn on or off reminder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Is it a good idea to mix a reminder with other information?**

Only if it's 100% relevant to the issue on hand and if something has changed. Such as something to add, or something to remove etc.

**If we do, should it still be written as a reminder with the data being extra, or just forget the reminder part, thinking about the product will be enough as a reminder so no need to mention it?**

Have an Update section underneath the original reminder with all that has changed. Keep the original though so your users know the timeline of said memo.